# Why is rpc.lockd obscured from netstat/lsof output?

Tags: linux, nfs, netstat, rpc, lsof

**Prologue:**

On a number of machines, which happen to act as NFS clients, `netstat` reports two ports that are open with no PID listed for an associated daemon. Ordinarily this might be a bit concerning.

```
# netstat -lnp | egrep -- '- +$'
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:57448           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     -
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:48933           0.0.0.0:*                          -
```

Additionally `netcat` confirms that the TCP port really is open.

```
# nc -v localhost 57448
localhost [127.0.0.1] 57448 (?) open
^C
```

Yet `lsof` reports nothing for these two ports. Intrigue grows.

```
# lsof -i TCP:57448 -i UDP:48933
```

However `rpcinfo` finally points us in the right direction. It's being held open by `nlockmgr`, aka `lockd` for NFS. Call off the search.

```
# rpcinfo -p | egrep '57448|48933'
    100021    1   udp  48933  nlockmgr
    100021    3   udp  48933  nlockmgr
    100021    4   udp  48933  nlockmgr
    100021    1   tcp  57448  nlockmgr
    100021    3   tcp  57448  nlockmgr
    100021    4   tcp  57448  nlockmgr
```

It becomes clear that `lockd`/`rpc.lockd` is called when mounting an NFS export. This is a kernel thread (is it always?) which binds itself to one TCP and one UDP port in the ephemeral range. The ports are typically reconfigurable with the `fs.nfs.nlm_tcpport` and `fs.nfs.nlm_udpport` sysctls.

**Questions:**

I am intrigued though. Would love some kernel-internals insight as to..

1. Why isn't the kernel thread's PID visible from `netstat`?
2. Why aren't the bound ports visible from `lsof`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

netstat and lsof both crawl `/proc/<pid>/fd` to associate processes to ports/sockets, and `/proc/<pid>/fd` doesn't get populated for kernel threads AFAIK.

lockd is always a kernel thread - at least on modern (newer than say 2.2) kernels.